# Can I store DLL/EXE artifact produced by VS C++ projects in NuGet packages?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, repository, nuget

We use VS2012 for developing C++ project which produce DLLs and EXEs.

We need a possibility of storing the produced artifacts in a module repository and are thinking about NuGet.

Can NuGet be used for this purpose? If not, is there something like 'Nexus for artifacts generated by VS C++ projects'?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to use it for that purpose. I did a proof of concept using Nexus (that currently supports NuGet) and I was able to store a NuGet package containing "custom content". This is what I did:

1. I created a simple c# project.
2. Run *nuget pack ...* to generate the nupkg package. The .nupkg file is basically a zip file
3. I unzipped the nupkg file and edited the content, putting my "custom files" in the "lib" folder. I also edited the metadata in the .nuspec file
4. I re-created the nupkg package manually, that is: I just zipped the folder and renamed the resulting file
5. I pushed the package to Nexus by executing *nuget push .....*

Hope this helps.

Comment: How did you define the meta data? I am currently trying to find a way to place an exe in the output directory of the project(s) that reference the nuget.